# Deleting Umbraco nforum user?

Tags: umbraco

I am trying to delete nforum user which was created hust for testing purposes but unfortunately I can't find anywhere instruction how to delete this user. I also can't find it in nforum Umbraco administration.

Any help is appreciated and many tahnks in advance!
MC2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought nForum uses Members of umbraco.

You can find the members section next to "users" in the lower left corner of your screen.
If it's there, you should add permissions to your user for this section.

Comment: I have created one test user BUT I can't see that user anywhere under 'Users' in Umbraco and that is the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Dampee is correct, all nForum members are in the Members section of Umbraco. But be careful, if you delete a member that has created topics or posts then you are likely to break the forum as those topics will try and load the member (Which won't exist now as you have deleted them)

Comment: I have created one test user BUT I can't see that user anywhere under 'Users' in Umbraco and that is the problem..

Comment: MEMBERS <<< Users are Umbraco users that login to Umbraco, 'Members'  are the members that your code or nForum creates. I suggest you have a little read up about the difference between a 'User' and a 'Member' in Umbraco.